# How to visualise .obj files in colab?

Tags: 3d, google-colaboratory, visualization, object-files

I have a generated obj file which I want to visualise in google colab.

What's the easiest way to visualise it directly in google colab?

A (admittely mild) google search did not return much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Open3D & Plotly to achieve this. Here is a notebook with various examples https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CR_HDvJ2AnjJV3Bf5vwP70K0hx3RcdMb?usp=sharing. The visualization of `bunny.obj` seems relevant to your case.